# Pair and Connect to a BLE device from inside an app behaves differently on Pixel 3a and 4a

Tags: bluetooth-pairing, android-11, bluetooth-le

After migrating from a Pixel 3a to a Pixel 4a (both running Android 11), re-connecting the GoPlus (a BLE accessory) in Pokémon GO now requires two more actions, first a notification "Pairing request" where I need to click "Pair & Connect" and then I need to press "Pair" on a popup in the middle of the screen "Pair with Pokémon GO Plus" (where I can decide if I want to share contacts and call history). Unfortunately, Niantic un-pairs the device after one hour, so when you want to reconnect, it is no longer paired in Android.

This is the exact same app running on the exact same version of Android, but on a device "one generation" newer. It seems strange that there would be a difference in how this works?

Is there some kind of permission I can grant Pokémon GO with "pm grant" from an ADB shell, or some other setting I can change, to just allow Pokémon GO-initiated pair and connects to BLE-accessories without user interaction?

("dumpsys package com.nianticlabs.pokemongo" shows that both devices already include android.permission.BLUETOOTH and android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN under "requested permissions").

Comment: Actually it is not strange, in the 3A the GoPlus was paired on Android 10 initially, so it's properties carried over after the upgrade 11 and everything stayed the same as long as it was not completely removed from the device. Once you went to the 4A, it was a new connection on 11. I literally deal with the same thing going from a 3A XL to a 4A.

Comment: Reading what you wrote, I think you are saying that something was "saved" about this BLE device, that does not exist on the new phone. That sounds logical - but my question is, what exactly is that, and how can I create/save the same information, from scratch, in Android 11, so I can get back the old behaviour. If the answer is "you can't", it would be nice if someone had pointers to where I can read more details about this change in android 11 and understand it better...